# Bound for $\left\|\nabla^2 u\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, perturbation-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Consider the elliptic equation
$$
\begin{aligned}
-\nabla \cdot A \nabla u=f, & \text { in } \Omega, \\
u=0, & \text { on } \partial \Omega.
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain. Suppose there is the regularity assumptions $u\in H^2$. In the paper I am reading, it mentions that  even if the coefficient is smooth, say at frequency $\varepsilon^{-1}$ for some small parameter $\varepsilon$, $\nabla^2 u$ may oscillate at the same scale, a fact that is hidden in the constant $\left\|\nabla^2 u\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \approx \varepsilon^{-1}$.

**Q: how to prove $\left\|\nabla^2 u\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \approx \varepsilon^{-1}$?**

This is the paper :  [enter link description here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.0692.pdf)